# Why can't TypeScript find modules that are installed into 'node_modules'?

Tags: typescript, npm, tsconfig

Given the following directory structure:

```
{project}/
  |-- node_modules/
  |    |-- lodash
  |-- src/
  |    |-- index.ts
  |-- lib/ (output)
  |    |-- index.js
  |    |-- index.d.ts
  |-- package.json
  |-- tsconfig.json
```

Whilst the built output functions properly; the `tsc` command complains that it cannot resolve the lodash module when I use any of the following:

```
import _ from "lodash";
import _ = require("lodash");
import * as _ from "lodash";
```

Inside my 'tsconfig.json' file I have included the following things:

```
...

"target": "es6",
"sourceMap": true,
"module": "commonjs",
"moduleResolution": "node",

...
```

But despite this it's still not finding any of the modules that are installed using npm.

Am I missing something that is required to make TypeScript find these modules?

I realize that without a TypeScript definition file TypeScript is unable to provide additional type checks; however, surely these should just default to the `any` type right?

Comment: Make sure you have Typescript 1.6 or higher. Here is a [good discussion](https://medium.com/@mweststrate/how-to-create-strongly-typed-npm-modules-1e1bda23a7f4#.ci86154ph) of how it "worked" prior to 1.6 and how it works after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since lodash doesn't have a definition file in the node_modules/lodash folder, that won't work. You'll have to download it using typings or use an ambient declaration instead of an import:

```
declare var _: any;
```

For node.js you'd have to use:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
```